# In Matlab with listdlg is it possible to select multiple options?

Tags: matlab, listview, user-interface

The list I have in Matlab is very long and I would like to be able to select multiple entries at one time from `listdlg`. Has anyone found out how to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Multiple selection is the default mode for `listdlg`. Unless I'm missing something from your explanation, the answer is "yes, and you don't have to do nothing special for it, unless pressing [CTRL] while clicking items"

Answer (score 0):

To call the `listdlg` with multiple selection enabled, just don't specify `'SelectionMode'` parameter to `'single'` value (i.e. use the defaults).

At runtime, in Windows/Linux environment, press `[CTRL]` key while single-clicking items for multiple selection. Not sure how works for Mac though...